# can not run my cordova app in new ios8

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8

Hi I am newbie to cordova development. I have develop an app in cordova thats was working perfectly in my previous version of ipad. After upgrading to new ios, it is not running in my ipad. Xcode shows me this error.

*Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is possibly due to the using non-compatible version of xcode with ios for development. If your app is running perfectly on previous ios and you are facing this error after upgrading your device ios, then upgrade you xcode with the recent version and then compile the project and test it on device. It will resolve your problem.**I was also facing this issue after upgrading my device to ios8. After installing xcode6 beta, I have no longer seen this error.**

Comment: I am using currently xcode5 and my device have installed ios 8. This error occurs after upgrading my device to ios8, before this it was working fine.

Comment: Yes you have to update xcode to the new version. Hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select below 8.0. Select 7.1 or 7.0 for recommendation.

[image]

Comment: I my xcode there is not 8.0 version availability. Latest option is 7.1 and this not works Oops!!